# Azure Web Service: Calling Multiple web services from a single webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, azure

So to summarise,

- VS 2015 community
- SQL Express 2016
- Azure Machine Learning
- Azure Webservice

Process Flow:

User inputs specific data from drop down lists, This data is used as parameters to call a stored procedure on the DB which returns data to a gridview(being sent to a gridview for testing purposes), this data is then passed to an Azure Machine learning webservice and returns/displays the web services prediction.

I have it working for one service(invokeResponseServiceFT) but the end goal is to have 7 services all running from the same webpage (as they all use the same params it should not be an overload of forms for end users).

Now the issue has arose when adding a second service, I'm receiving this error when it is called:

> "StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { x-ms-request-id:
>   fa6ae7d9-63c9-48ee-bf8a-c455838d905d Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2017 11:05:41
>   GMT ETag: "db595771cdbd434aa2a92609518f0aad" Server:
>   Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Content-Length: 319 Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8 }"

I've double checked the post url and api key both are correct. Json structure is exactly the same so just reusing from the 1st service. A little loss as to what the issue is. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /// string connectionString = SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;
    }

//json structure

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Results Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public Output1 output1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Output1
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
        public string[] ColumnTypes { get; set; }
        public string[][] Values { get; set; }
    }

    // Start of Azure Machine Learning web service 
    public class StringTable
    {
        public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
        public string[,] Values { get; set; }
    }

    // public keyword added in front of async
    // "string[] inputparams, Label label" added to function 
    public async Task InvokeRequestResponseServiceFT(string[] inputparams, Label label)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var scoreRequest = new
            {
                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, StringTable>() {
                        {
                            "input1",
                            new StringTable()
                            {
                                ColumnNames = new string[] {"Venue", "TeamA", "TeamB", "TP", "AHT12", "BHT12", "SPFT12", "SPHT12", "SP2HT12", "GFT12", "GHT12", "G2HT12", "GFT", "GHT", "G2HT", "SPFT", "SPHT", "SP2HT", "AFT", "BFT", "AHT", "BHT", "AVGFT"},
           // test data Values = new string[,] {  { "Glasgow", "Glasgow", "Leinster",  "85", "85", "85", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21" }, }
                               Values = new string[,] {  { inputparams[0], inputparams[1], inputparams[2],  inputparams[3], inputparams[4], inputparams[5],inputparams[6],inputparams[7],inputparams[8],inputparams[9],inputparams[10],inputparams[11],inputparams[12],inputparams[13],inputparams[14],inputparams[15],inputparams[16],inputparams[17],inputparams[18],inputparams[19],inputparams[20],inputparams[21],inputparams[22] }, }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                }
            };
            // 3. TO DO: Update apiKey
            const string apiKey = "api key"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

            // 4. TO DO: Replace following line client.BaseAddress with the corresponding from web service
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("post address");

            // ".ConfigureAwait(false)" appended to call as we are calling this function from UI
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // The following lines were added:
                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                // This deserialization will only work if the corresponding C# classes are defined for JSON.
                Rootobject myresults = ser.Deserialize<Rootobject>(result);

                var score = myresults.Results.output1.value.Values; //from C# classes defined above from JSON output

                string scoredlabels = score[0][0];
                string scoredprobabilities = score[0][23];

                ResultsLabel.Text = scoredprobabilities;
            }
            else
            {
                ResultsLabel.Text = "the script hasn't worked";
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ////HT JSON
    /// </summary>

    // public keyword added in front of async
    // "string[] inputparams, Label label" added to function 
    public async Task InvokeRequestResponseServiceHT(string[] inputparams, Label label)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var scoreRequest = new
            {
                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, StringTable>() {
                        {
                            "input1",
                            new StringTable()
                            {
                                ColumnNames = new string[] {"Venue", "TeamA", "TeamB", "TP", "AHT12", "BHT12", "SPFT12", "SPHT12", "SP2HT12", "GFT12", "GHT12", "G2HT12", "GFT", "GHT", "G2HT", "SPFT", "SPHT", "SP2HT", "AFT", "BFT", "AHT", "BHT", "AVGFT"},
           //Test Data Values = new string[,] {  { "Glasgow", "Glasgow", "Leinster",  "85", "85", "85", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21" }, }
                               Values = new string[,] {  { inputparams[0], inputparams[1], inputparams[2],  inputparams[3], inputparams[4], inputparams[5],inputparams[6],inputparams[7],inputparams[8],inputparams[9],inputparams[10],inputparams[11],inputparams[12],inputparams[13],inputparams[14],inputparams[15],inputparams[16],inputparams[17],inputparams[18],inputparams[19],inputparams[20],inputparams[21],inputparams[22] }, }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                }
            };
            // 3. TO DO: Update apiKey using value from your web service on Machine Learning portal
            const string apiKey = "api key"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

            // 4. TO DO: Replace following line client.BaseAddress with the corresponding one from web service
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("////post address ");

            // ".ConfigureAwait(false)" appended to call as we are calling this function from UI
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                // deserialization
                Rootobject myresults = ser.Deserialize<Rootobject>(result);

                var score = myresults.Results.output1.value.Values; //from C# classes defined above from JSON output

                string scoredlabels = score[0][0];
                string scoredprobabilities = score[0][23];

                // 5. TO DO: format the return value
                ResultsHT.Text = scoredprobabilities;
            }
            else
            {
                // Request was not successful - could be incorrect APIKey, missing values, etc...
                ResultsHT.Text = "the script hasn't worked";//response.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a using statement to handle your Connection
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString))
        {
            //Open your connection
            sqlConnection.Open();

            //Build your Command (and denote it is a stored procedure)
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Getdetails", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Add your parameters (assuming they are defined the same within your Stored Procedure
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Venue", DDVenue.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamA", DDTeamA.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamB", DDTeamB.Text);

            try
            {
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                //Just execute the Query directly
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                da.Fill(DS);
                GridView1.DataSource = DS;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                string[] inputparams = new string[DS.Tables[0].Columns.Count];

                for (int col = 0; col < DS.Tables[0].Columns.Count; ++col)
                {
                    inputparams[col] = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0][col].ToString();
                }
                InvokeRequestResponseServiceFT(inputparams, ResultsLabel).Wait();
                InvokeRequestResponseServiceHT(inputparams, ResultsHT).Wait();
                //  Clear();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,

When assigning values to specific columns for the json request, I had made a typo with one of the column names....so in the InvokeRequestResponseServiceHT method, one of the columns was referred to as "TP" where it should have been "HTP"...annoying to say the least!